# Use Type annotation in AWS using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, types, boto3

I want to start to use typed Python.

Is there any documentation with all types for AWS?

For instance, where can I find type for **sns_client = boto3.client('sns')**?
or **lambda_handler** event and stufs like this?

Is there any documentation or guideline with all these types?

Thank you for answer !

Comment: Use some combination of boto3-stubs and CodeWhisperer.